# Dart-Code is switching to using the Language Server Protocol for improved performance. Would you like to enable it now?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

What does it mean? Any benefit of enabling them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Initially let's first understand what is a `Language Server Protocol`.**

[Language Server Protocol (LSP)](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) :

> The Language Server Protocol (LSP) defines the protocol used between
> an editor or IDE and a language server that provides language features
> like auto complete, go to definition, find all references etc. The
> goal of the Language Server Index Format (LSIF, pronounced like "else
> if") is to support rich code navigation in development tools or a Web
> UI without needing a local copy of the source code.

Dart Code announced few months earlier that they will switch to the Language Server Protocol for communicating with the Dart Language Server and this is being implemented now. [See here](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-16/)

**Advantages of using Language Server Protocol (LSP) :**

- Auto Complete
- Documentation on hover
- Go to definition

*Enabling it will give you a better coding experience with hints, auto completes etc which comes from the Dart Language Server instead of a local copy.*

Comment: The last few things here under "Advantages" are not quite accurate. These things were already available before LSP, they just used a custom Dart-server protocol to implement them. Mostly the process of moving to LSP should be invisible to users, although there are some specific things (like code completion) that should work better due to having less work sharing a thread with all other VS Code extensions.